# getting the roi section dynamically ignoring resize

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

i have a set of resolution for opencv and pytesseract to detect which is the standard 1920x1080

but after getting the image and resize it to 1920x1080, i will get the ROI around center square of the image

```
img = cv2.imread("test.png")
height, width, channels = img.shape 
print(f'original size / w = {width}, h = {height}')

img = image_resize(img, width=1920, height=1080)
height, width, channels = img.shape
print(f'after resize / w = {width}, h = {height}')

x, y, w, h = 466, 203, 978, 760
roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

something like this to crop out the image, but i found out if my image is not native 1920x1080, which either is from bigger or smaller resolution and resize to 1920x1080, this fixed roi x,y,w,h is not working well. i would like to know a better way to dynamically scale the ROI values from different resolution.

using this resize method i found in stackoverflow as well.

```
def image_resize(image, width = None, height = None, inter = cv2.INTER_AREA):
    # initialize the dimensions of the image to be resized and
    # grab the image size
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    # if both the width and height are None, then return the
    # original image
    if width is None and height is None:
        return image

    # check to see if the width is None
    if width is None:
        # calculate the ratio of the height and construct the
        # dimensions
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)

    # otherwise, the height is None
    else:
        # calculate the ratio of the width and construct the
        # dimensions
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    # resize the image
    resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = inter)

    # return the resized image
    return resized
```

Comment: Where are you getting the values for x,y,w,h?

Comment: hardcoded by myself but this is the region i am interested

Comment: Is it in the original image space or the resized image space?

Comment: is in the resized image space, 1920x1080. basically i am setting that all the screenshot getting is to be size of 1920x1080